# How to control motor in trapezoidal manner using arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, c++, motor, c

I am Working on a project in that i have to control motor in a Trapezoidal motion profile. on Y-axis is the velocity and X- axis as a time.
Velocity increases linearly for a certain time, then constant velocity for certain time and then Linearly decreasing the velocity and stop the motor

Comment: What kind of motor? Step motor? DC brushed? Does it have an optical encoder? How much non-linearity can you tolerate on the acceleration profile?

Comment: It is a BLDC motor, With 3000 PPR Optical Encoder. And i just want a trapezoidal motion, after that i can tweak accordingly

Comment: Hint: Start by trying to write this from an API point of view. What library function(s) are you looking for? How would you like to express this in a sketch?